# ♥ character displayed incorrectly in Glyphs

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am using the Glyphs class to display text in a Windows Phone 7 app. There is a ♥ character in the text, which is not getting displayed. The usual unicode empty rectangle for missing character is shown.
The same string is displayed correctly in a TextBlock, and if I debug and look at the UnicodeString property of the Glyphs object, then the ♥ symbol is displayed correctly in the watch window.

What could be the problem? I couldn't find any information about the topic.

UPDATE: I am using the Segoe WP font (SegoeWP.ttf). I tried to copy paste this symbol into a Word document, and if I try to set its font to Segoe WP, it automatically changes back to Arial (the same happens with a lot of other fonts, like Tahoma, Verdana, etc). However, if I set its font to Segoe UI or Segoe Symbol, it switches to that, and the look of the heart symbol is also slightly changed.

Is it possible, that this symbol is missing from the Segoe WP font, but it is included in Segoe UI and Segoe Symbol? And if so, why does it work correctly in a TextBlock? Doesn't it use Segoe WP on Windows Phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Glyphs class states in [its documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.glyphs%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) that:

> Font fallback is not supported, and all characters must be supported by the specified font file.

The documentation suggests that the suggests that a TextBlock should be used in situations where layout and substitution issues haven't been specifically taken care of.

Comment: That limitation is only applied to Glyphs without the Indices property, but I provide the indices. My current suspicion is that the font fyle I am using (Segoe WP) does not contain this symbol (more detail in the question).

Comment: The TextBlock does the font substitution for you, and no, that font doesn't have a glyph for that codepoint.

Comment: I accepted the answer, the base problem was that Glyphs does not fall back to another font if a symbol is missing. The solution for me was to change the font family (from Segoe WP to Segoe UI), another solution - if applicable - would be to switch to TextBlock, however, that was not possible in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the font file for the Glyphs from Segoe WP to Segoe UI, and it solved the problem. It's surprising to me, because I thought that Windows Phone used Segoe WP by default. It seems it doesn't, or at least not the version which gets installed into C:\Windows\Fonts with Visual Studio 2010 (or it falls back to Segoe UI or Symbol when it finds a missing symbol).

(Is there a way to get the ttf font file directly from a WP7 device?)